# How do I import installed npm modules to be to use them on my html file

Tags: javascript, html, css, git, npm

How do I import a node module to HTML?
I cloned this repo from GitHub and it uses npm and other npm dependencies for the project.

I want to add  particules.js  to one part of the site.
But now I don't know how to import npm modules to use them at the HTML page

Using script tag to add the required file from the src folders returns an error from webpack not been able to compile and understand the script

I want to figure out how to import node modules that are already installed and use them on my HTML

Sorry for my bad enjoy, thanks.

Adding to this
I followed the instructions on the GitHub page
https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js/

```
var particlesJs = require("particles.js");

particlesJS.load('particles-js', 'particles.json', function() {
console.log('callback - particles-js config loaded');
});
```

It returned an error from webpack that the window is not defined.

I said let me try and use browserify and bundle the script. It returned same error here

Html Webpack Plugin:
  Error: C:\Users\MATRIX\desktop\simplefolio/src/bundle.js?:1430
  window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
  ^
  ReferenceError: window is not defined

Comment: You can use [Browserify](http://browserify.org).

Comment: I followed the instructions on the github page to import the module

var particlesJs = require("particles.js");

particlesJS.load('particles-js', 'particles.json', function() {
console.log('callback - particles-js config loaded');
});
My package.json is on the same dir as my html
It returned an error from webpack that window is not defined.

I used browserify, bundled the script. It returned same error here

Html Webpack Plugin:
  Error: C:\Users\MATRIX\desktop\simplefolio/src/bundle.js?:1430
  window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
  ^
  ReferenceError: window is not defined